# jQuery not firing click events for button in IE

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie of jQuery. Now I'm trying to intercept click login button that I've create with id='btnL' with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {
    $("#btnL").click(function() {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
})();

</script>
```

I've put this code inside a body but i don't know why it works correctly on FireFox and Chrome, but it not works fine in Internet Explorer.
How can i solve it? which is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: IE tends to kill JS if there is an error - are you getting any JS errors?

Comment: no error in my browser! it's very simple code! and i've try also with $ but nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing $ at the beginning. This should work.

```
  $(function() {
        $("#btnL").click(function() {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        });
    });
```

Here is the working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/ftfaF/

Comment: i try but this not works for my IE9. this is my doctype:<!DOCTYPE html> with <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

Comment: @jack.cap.rooney : This should work. Did you clear the browser cache ? I guess there is some other script error. what are u seeing in firebug console ?

Comment: @jack.cap.rooney : check the jsfiddle i added to my answer

Comment: no others script! no erro in firebug, in FireFox it works correctly! only in IE (i've just clear cache)

Comment: @Shyju isn't it fun when you answer the question first (scroll to the bottom) but then someone comes in with roughly the same answer, and gets the correct answer because they're answer appears above older answers :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have a $ at the start of your function, $(function ... not sure if that is the problem without testing it, as I'm on my phone writing this answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems.

You should have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnL").click(function() {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        });
    });
```

like the others say but also in your URL for the Google API. You have 3 backslashes when you should have 2.